# Android Screen mirroring via rtsp server

Tags: android, ffmpeg, adb, screen, rtsp

I was trying to mirror my android phone's screen to my PC. I actually did that thanks to `ffplay` and `adb`. But my question is how I can send it to an `rtsp` server. Do I need any additional stuff besides them?

What I can do :

```
adb exec-out screenrecord --output-format=h264 - | ffplay -
```

I completely didn't understand how to send this output to an rtsp server and I don't know if there is additional thing rather than rtsp I will be so appreciated if you help me. Thanks.

Comment: you figured the `adb` part already. now you just need a proper `ffmpeg` command to stream your screen cast. it's not a software development problem.

Comment: Okay but do I need anything more ? Are there any rtsp server which is available for commercial use?